# How to wrap WebExtensions notifications in a Promise?

Tags: promise, firefox-addon

Notifications are small modal boxes that can be used in Firefox WebExtensions code to display messages, similar to "alert()". How to wrap them in Promises so that they have enough time to appear on the screen and then get dismissed automatically? (I'm going to answer my own question.)

Answer (score 0):

This code defines a function S() that displays a string with a given title in a notification box that stays on the screen for 3 seconds. The code returns a Promise that waits for 1/2 a second, until the box actually appears.

Usage: S('string you want to display','title of notification box').then(nextFunction);

```
// Wrap setTimeout in a Promise
function delay(msec,value)
    {
    return new Promise(function(OKFunction)
        {
        setTimeout(OKFunction,msec,value);
        });
    } // delay

// S: Promise to show string in notification box
// with delays before continuing and before clearing the box
function S(Msg,Title)
    {
    var p=browser.notifications.create({
        "type": "basic",
        "iconUrl": browser.extension.getURL("icons/link-48.png"), // change this as desired
        "title": Title,
        "message": Msg});
    p.then(S1);
    return delay(500); // Wait for notification to appear before continuing
    } // S
function S1(ID)
    {   delay(3000,ID).then(S2).catch(err); } // S1
function S2(ID)
    {   browser.notifications.clear(ID).then(empty).catch(err); } // S2

function empty(valueIgnored)
    {
    console.log('doing nothing');
    } // empty

function err(Msg)
    {
    console.log('*** '+Msg);
    throw Error;
    } // err
```